# Synchronize date format between frontend and backend

Tags: c#, angularjs, datetime, asp.net-web-api, culture

Let's assume we have an application consists of angularjs frontend and asp.net wep api as backend.

Client should use his culture(eg: En-US) when use datepicker. When data will post to backend side I have a specific culture there(eg: Tr-TR).

I want to a system to handle date time format to manage this situation easily. For example whenever client send a request to backend, I should learn his culture from request, then convert my dates to that format while serializing before returning the data.

What type of system I should create?

Since I haven't frontend code yet, I'll share my culture configuration on web api side.

**Setting culture**

```
public class CultureConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        //Get the culture info of the language code
        const string uiLanguage = "Tr";//"En-US";
        var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(uiLanguage);
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
    }
}
```

**Json Serializing Configs:**

```
  var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
            DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Unspecified,
            Culture = CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture
        };
```

Comment: Could you provide a pointer to the specific datepicker component you are using? It's hard to help without knowing more details about what you might have implemented and relying only on assumptions.

Comment: Hi, @DarinDimitrov Actually I'm relying only on assumption. I haven't started to write frontend side yet. I'm just creating my infrastructure on web api side. Then this question came to my mind. I think no matter what the datepicker is. Just asume there are data coming from client with different cultures and I have to handle them on backen side.

Comment: In this case just ensure that the frontend always sends the dates in UTC. That's how you definitely want them to be stored in your backend. Unfortunately since you haven't provided any concrete details about the specific components you are using, nor the serialization protocol, this question hardly makes any sense and probably should be closed.

Comment: I added codes I have about culture. I hope it'll help to clarify something

Comment: I repeat my advice once again - use UTC and ISO8601 format for serialization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You tagged this as being about Web API and Angular, which is a beautiful combination that makes dates slightly less really-difficult.

A couple tricks to keep in mind, given that:

- Keep everyone on UTC. Client sends UTC up, server sends UTC down. If you use the `date` filter that Angular has built-in, it'll automatically adjust any UTC dates to local browser time. Similarly, `input[type="datetime-local"]` elements will perform that conversion as well.
- Serialize using ISO formats. JSON.net will do that by default; don't change it. If you send a `DateTime` object down as `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`, any client framework (including Angular) will parse it correctly. Even from a philosophical perspective, think about it: your backend shouldn't be formatting dates for your view to display, it should just give a date object. JSON doesn't have "date objects," so we pick the next closest thing.

Essentially, don't let your Web Api worry about culture. Part of what's nice about APIs is that they're so flexible. Let your front-end framework worry about how to display dates under what circumstances. It happens that Angular is very good at this.

If you keep it to that, everything will run smoothly and be easily maintainable.

There are sometimes some weird edge-cases where you have to add modifications in to support this, and it might be easier to change cultures server-side or store things in local time (like, Entity Framework requires a helper to tell it that all `DateTime` values should have their kinds changed to `Utc`, otherwise JSON.net will serialize them as local time, and they'll be off by your UTC offset). But take it from someone who's been there, it's worth doing it right in the long-run. Add whatever helpers are necessary to make all of the above happen, and it'll work like a charm.

Comment: It's really useful explanation for me. Just to be sure, you say use Json.Net with default settings so It'll use UTC. In addition, Don't set culture info at all. So should I remove my CultureConfig? Then what about database(Entity Framework) part. Should I save there as UTC as well?

Comment: @mavera Yep, save things to EF in UTC. There are a few questions here on [so] about using UTC with EF that might be worth checking out, because it'll default to `Unspecified` when it materializes `DateTime` objects, so you have to fix that up. But yes, I'd remove all your `CultureConfig` stuff. Maybe just comment it to make sure we haven't missed anything, but I've worked on a number of successful APIs that never needed anything like that, so I can't think of why you would.